# Unit Testing directive that adds class to element

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I have the following jsbin http://jsbin.com/uvipos/1/edit

With a custom directive that adds .active to a parent element if the link it contains is the link to the page we are on (for bootstrap for example). The directive works just fine, but I am struggling to figure out how to test it.

The directive:

```
  app.directive('whenChildActive', ['$location', function ($location) {
    return {
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$on( '$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
          var literalLink = element.find('a').attr( 'href' );

          var currentPath = $location.path();
          var hashPath = '#' + currentPath;
          if ( currentPath === literalLink || hashPath === literalLink) {
            element.addClass( 'active' );
          } else {
            element.removeClass( 'active' );
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

My test attempt:

```
describe('Directive: whenChildActive', function () {
  beforeEach(module('myNgApp'));

  var element;
  var envs = [
    'http://server/#/app',
  ], count = 0;

  beforeEach(inject(function($browser){
    $browser.url(envs[count++]);
  }));

  it('should add class when child href matches location', inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    element = angular.element('<li when-child-active><a href="#/app">Some Text</a>/li>');
    element = $compile(element)($rootScope);

    expect(element.hasClass('active')).toBe(true);
  }));
});
```

My test fails, and i am unsure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the route after you compiled the element - in between `element = $compile(element)($rootScope);` and `expect(element.hasClass('active')).toBe(true);`, insert a line like `$browser.url(envs[count++])` and what you get.

Comment: Thank you for your help on IRC so much.  `$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess');` after the compile fixed it